# Prove that the shortest path between two vertices in a weighted graph does not change if we multiply weights with the same number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I need help to prove that if we multiply weights with the same positive number , in a weighted graph, the shortest path between two vertices does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a shortest path with weights $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_j$ in the original graph.  Then for every alternative path with weights $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_k$ in the original graph you have $\sum a_i \leq \sum b_i$

Suppose we multiply all of the weights in the graph by $\alpha>0$.  Compare now the path with weights $\alpha a_1,\alpha a_2,\dots, \alpha a_j$ to the path with weights $\alpha b_1, \alpha b_2,\dots, \alpha b_k$

Given that $\sum a_i\leq \sum b_i$ does it follow that $\sum \alpha a_i \leq \sum \alpha b_i$?

> Yes, of course since $\sum \alpha a_i = \alpha \left(\sum a_i\right) \leq \alpha \left(\sum b_i\right) = \sum \alpha b_i$

Since it was not specified which of the specific alternative paths the second path was, that implies that all alternative second paths satisfy this inequality and therefore the first path is still the shortest available, even after the multiplication by $\alpha$.

Comment: I was attempting to write down total path length ($\sum_{i=1}^k b_i$)  as a function of the weights of the edges $(b_1,b_2,\dots,b_k)$ used in the path in order to emphasize that total path length will by multiplied by $\alpha$ when each edge weight is multiplied by $\alpha$.  Here, the shortest path from a source to a sink uses the sequence of edge-weights $a_1,a_2,\dots$ while some arbitrarily chosen alternative path from source to sink uses the sequence of edge-weights $b_1,b_2,\dots$.  I opted to use a different letter since it is possible parts of the path to be repeated between the two.